# Compatibility Liferay 5 with jboss 7

Tags: jboss, liferay

I have a working liferay 5 in jboss 4 server.

I have to migrate same liferay application to jboss version 7 .

I follow the steps written in following link

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen11-installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-0

and I get the following error:

> 06:46:03,114 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".POST_MODULE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase
>   POST_MODULE of deployment "ROOT.war"  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>   [classes.jar:1.6.0_37] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
>   getting reflective information for class
>   com.liferay.taglib.ui.InputPermissionsParamsTag with ClassLoader
>   ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service
>   Module Loader     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     ... 5 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/MethodWrapper  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>   [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
>   [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
>   [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]    at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     ... 10 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodWrapper from [Module
>   "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>     ... 15 more

I tried to debug the error but not able to find any solution .

Is Liferay 5 compatible with jboss 7. If yes, how to resolve the above error?

Answer (score 0):

You're following the instructions to install Liferay 6.1 on JBoss 7, but you claim you're installing Liferay 5.x - which is an at least 5 years old version of Liferay, potentially requiring different steps to setup. Without looking it up, the odds are that nobody ever documented this kind of setup and you should seriously consider not only upgrading JBoss, but also Liferay.

If you're desperate to make it run, try manually installing Liferay 6.1 on JBoss 7 and verify you did all the correct steps, then go back version by version (e.g. 6.0, 5.2) and make sure to start with a vanilla (unchanged) Liferay version, then add your customizations. But, seriously, it's a bad idea to keep a 5 year old unmaintained software running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have this five year old version of life ray ,thats why I am trying to migrate to server . But due to time dependency I am not able to migrate the liferay version 6.x . If any one had gone under this situation just let me know.

Comment: For your reference I have installed life ray 5.x in tomcat 7 and its working fine.

Comment: I expect it to work somehow, but am somewhat reluctant to try out this combination. After all - installing such an old version is disadvised, and it feels wrong to give advice on how to do things that are recommended to not do them.